# What should be the ideal value for I controller in PID for a quadracopter

Tags: c++, arduino, pid-controller

I am making a quadracopter using Arduino, gyro and accelerometer, 1000kv motor with 30A esc.
While writing the program for flight control I am doubtful of the value to be used for 'I' controller in PID algorithm. I tried to set the value between 1.0 to 1.5 but the copter would drift apart to much.
I have set Maximum PID output to 400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about stabilizing closed loop control system. Either you can tune the gain with trial and error method or do a theoretical analysis of system. I would suggest you refer manual for a range of values and then try to find suitable value with trail and error method. By the way this question doesn't suit SO.

Comment: "*By the way this question doesn't suit SO.*" Then don't answer such questions.

Comment: That's what comments and flags (or close votes) are for.